# The elements displayed on Initial page?

Tags: fine-uploader

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yg47.png)

I want the elements ("button ... href...") to be displayed on the "Initial File List" page, how can I do it?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In add page

```
<ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
    <li>
        ...
        <button type="button" class="view-btn hide btn">View</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And Complete event handler like this:

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    ...
    callbacks: {
        onComplete: function(id, name, response) {
            var serverPathToFile = response.filePath,
                fileItem = this.getItemByFileId(id);

            if (response.success) {
                var viewBtn = qq(fileItem).getByClass("view-btn")[0];

                viewBtn.setAttribute("href", serverPathToFile);
                qq(viewBtn).removeClass("hide");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Now I want to edit the content,So I initialize this page

Edit page Like this:

```
<ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
    <li>
        ...
        <button type="button" class="view-btn btn" href="serverPathToFile">View</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can i get the 'serverPathToFile' in the edit page?

THANKS!

Comment: just add the elements to the appropriate place in your template

Comment: but how can I get the "serverPathToFile"?

Answer (score 0):

From the [server section](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/session.html#server) of the initial file list feature page:

> The response (from your server to Fine Uploader's initial file list GET request) will be converted into a JavaScript Array and passed to your [`sessionRequestComplete` event handler](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#sessionRequestComplete). So, any non-standard object properties passed with your server response will also be passed to your event handler.

So you can simply include any information you need in an appropriate property per-file, access it in your `sessionRequestComplete` event handler, and update the `document` as required.

Comment: Is it right?
onSessionRequestComplete: function(response,success){
         if (success == true) {
          $.each(response, function (i, file){
           $('.qq-file-id-'+i).find('.view-btn').attr('href',serverPathToFile);
          });
         };
        }

Comment: That works, but you should use the [getItemByFileId method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getItemByFileId) to locate the file element in the DOM instead of expecting a qq-file-id class to be there.

Comment: There has been such a mistake,zzzzzz：Caught exception in 'onSessionRequestComplete' callback - getItemByFileId is not defined

Comment: API methods are not global properties. That would be a horrible idea. You can access them all via the context of the callback function, also known as `this`.